# Universal Music Player with own JSON and Youtube Audio Library

Tags: android, json, youtube, audio-player, android-music-player

As mentioned in this line:

```
private static final String CATALOG_URL =
"http://storage.googleapis.com/automotive-media/music.json";
```

This file contains a `list of tracks` that are hosted by Google online.

So, I guess the complete URL of `Jazz_In_Paris.mp3` would be

```
https://www.youtube.com/audiolibrary/music/Jazz_In_Paris.mp3
```

but getting `404 Not Found` in a same way I have tried

```
https://www.youtube.com/audiolibrary/music/album_art.jpg
```

but again same result `404 Not Found`

So here are my few small `questions`:

```
1. What is the complete URL of `Jazz_In_Paris.mp3` and `album_art.jpg`

2. Where they have used site object "site" : "https://www.youtube.com/audiolibrary/music" in application (in which class and where)

3. Where I have to make changes in my code, If I would like to get JSON from my own Server "http://www.domain.com/services/music.json"

4. How can I create my own Youtube Audio Library, Like in my Library I would like to add my favourite youtube songs
```

Comment: this is correct path for both image and mp3 http://storage.googleapis.com/automotive-media/album_art.jpg and "site" : "https://www.youtube.com/audiolibrary/music" is not used any where in app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What is the complete URL of `Jazz_In_Paris.mp3` and `album_art.jpg`**

http://storage.googleapis.com/automotive-media/album_art.jpg

http://storage.googleapis.com/automotive-media/The_Messenger.mp3

---

**Where they have used site object "site" : "https://www.youtube.com/audiolibrary/music" in application (in which class and where)**

this url not used any where in app.

---

**Where I have to make changes in my code, If I would like to get JSON from my own Server "http://www.domain.com/services/music.json"**

yes, you can use same json for your app but just change path to your server(just create same json format)

---

**How can I create my own Youtube Audio Library, Like in my Library I would like to add my favourite youtube songs**

Universal Music Player: use Google storage client to store music files but you can also create own `you tube` channel and make private video. use it in your app

---

**EDITED:**

"site" json object is useless. this object is json because of previous version of app they have used that. currently not.

**youtube channel** and **Google storage** both are different thing. Google storage mainly used to store files which we are able to use in our app.

in you tube every one can upload video which is private/public(if you are going to use that in your app then use private). for more detail check you support [articals](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/57792?hl=en)

i suggest you to use [Google Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/) API or you can also upload files on your own server!

Comment: thank you so much :) for each and every step but still two small questions in my mind. Can I Ask ?

Comment: 1. If they are not using "site" json object in app, so why they have used in JSON. Is "site" json object is useless in short ? 2. Still confuse how can i create my own Youtube Audio library (The way to use Google storage client and how can i get Youtube Audio library of any youtube channel)

Comment: again tons of thanks, last question of the day UMP sample (supports minimum 21 api) but i have two (supports 4.4.2 and 4.2) devices [So I am not able to install my app on my devices], but I also want my app should support TV, Auto, Wear and I want to set (14 as min API) Is it possible ?

Comment: yes its possible just add support app to lower API(mean change some of code if there is any issue using support library v7, v13) & one app code work in all TV,Auto,Wear,Tablets, Phone. so its possible.

Comment: please check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34607919/not-getting-thumb-with-genres-universal-music-player